# Storing the values in list Python

Tags: python, list

In my below program I have used the append() function to store the entropy in a list.
I have 36 dialogs in the program and I want to store the entropy of one dialogue into the list and then update the values in the same variable for the second dialogues and for third dialogue entropy also update the values in the same list.

But append() function will append all the entropies for all the dialogues in the list but not updating the values.

My Program is below :

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from scipy.stats import entropy
from math import log10
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


store_entropy = []
critical_entropy = 0
position = 0
outputfile = open("Output.txt","w")
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        lines = filter(None, line[2:])
        lines1 = ' '.join(lines).split(',')

        for row in lines1[::]:
            makeOneLine = row.rstrip('\n')
            delimiter = " "
            makeOneLine = delimiter.join(makeOneLine.split(delimiter, 3))
            numpyArraysDisplay = np.array(list(makeOneLine.split(" ")))
            print(numpyArraysDisplay)
            outputfile.write(str(numpyArraysDisplay) + '\n')

        #Loop for first segment
            for x in range(0, numpyArraysDisplay.size):
                part1 = numpyArraysDisplay[:x + 1]  # First segment divide
                strings, counts = np.unique(part1, return_counts=True)
                CountWordsfrequency = np.array(list(dict(zip(strings, counts)).values()))
                print(CountWordsfrequency)
                outputfile.write(str(CountWordsfrequency) + '\n')

                for y in range(0, CountWordsfrequency.size):
                    probability = CountWordsfrequency[y]/ part1.size
                    outputfile.write("Probability is \t" + str(probability) + '\n')
            ent2 = entropy(counts,base=10)
            outputfile.write("Entropy is \t" + str(ent2) + '\n')
            store_entropy.append(ent2)
```

If I print `store_entropy` list then it will print all the values in the list from first dialogue to last. I want that first dialogue entropy store in variable and when loop run second time second dialogue entropy updates the first one not append it.

My output is :

```
[0.0, 0.30102999566398114, 0.4771212547196623, 0.4515449934959717,0.0,0.6179053239112496, 
 0.6135103844338377, 0.6097931356022916]
```

Expected is:

```
[0.0, 0.30102999566398114, 0.4771212547196623, 0.4515449934959717]
[0.0, 0.6179053239112496,0.6135103844338377, 0.6097931356022916]
```

Please tell me if anyone has solution.

Comment: Can I know the number of rows and columns  in `data.csv `

Comment: @Solen'ya : Rows = 36 and columns are not fixed.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Your code is difficult to read, since you're using at least 3 different naming conventions for variables. Also, please provide a [mcve]. As far as I can tell there's no reason to use NumPy arrays here, so that just further contributes to muddying the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the above problem and I have achieved expected output by below code.

```
size = len(store_entropy)
idx_list = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(store_entropy) if val == 0.0]
res = [store_entropy[i: j] for i, j in zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + ([size] if 
idx_list[-1] != size else []))]
# print(res)
res2 = [x for x in res if x != []]
print(res2)
```